# C# Winform Compilation Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compiler-errors, 64-bit

I have a winform c# app with a real text box that I use for logging output.  When I compile the app with "anycpu", i can view the main form (with the text box on it) just fine.  However, when I compile as x64 (which I need to do for ms database engine), it states could not find my logging control.  As soon as I go back to anycpu, again the form opens in designer just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your "logging control" compiled as?  IE is it x86 or 64(I'm assuming it's a control)

Comment: From my experience this is usually due to is misconfiguration of solution/project platforms. Double check the Configuration Manager (right click on your solution) has the correct platforms for each project. Also double check the Build tab in project properties for the correct Platform target.

Comment: the logging control is just a control in the app.  It's not compiled separately.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, in configuration manager I had active solution platform: x64 and the project platform as x64 and that was not working.  Switching the project platform to Any CPU at least for now enables me to view the form in design view so I guess it's fixed?

Comment: Nope, that just disabled the x64 compatibility of the app, breaking the odbc functions.